# Images of an angular app are not shown in browser

Tags: angular, image, browser, localhost

I am currently working on a sample angular app.
I want to display a list of products in my browser with images.

[image]

this is how products is defined (only first element displayed):

[image]

This is how its displayed in the browser:

[image]

I use Chrome, but its also the same with IE or Edge.
I can see the images, when i browse directly to the url.
I cant see them, when I use them in the app (http://localhost:4200).

[To look for the code on GitHub](https://github.com/hcetinkaya/ACMEStart.git)

I am working on a Win10 64-bit with Chrome version 71.0.3578.98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML. You are referencing `product.imageURL` when you should be referencing `product.imageUrl`.